# Is it ethical to make my team pay for a team bonding activity after work?

Tags: team, meetings, after-hours

If I make my team pay for a team bonding activity after work, can that be considered ethical?

Comment: It may or may not be ethical, but making your team pay for it will either defeat the purpose of the activity, or bond the team against you. This will be doubly so if the activity is compulsory.

Comment: Can you answer your own question? If so, what more do you need?

Comment: Is the event mandatory, or optional?

Comment: This is a win-lose situation which will demotivate employees. The way to do it is to do these events during company time with company funding, that will show your employees that the company is willing to make an effort.

Comment: They will put your head on a pike in the lobby as a warning to the next 10 generations to show what a stupid idea this is.  (Paraphrasing obscure SciFi).  Seriously - this is about as stupid as it gets.

Comment: For me, "Activity After Work" is an instant turn-off, regardless of who pays for it. I'm too busy after work to want to spend unpaid time with colleagues...

Comment: Please tell us more about the context. Is the event mandatory? Did the team have input on what will be done, and what the cost will be? Have you already discussed this with the team? What was the result? Voting to close as unclear.

Comment: You really need to add context about this team bonding.

Comment: There's a good and useful question somewhere in here, but it needs more meat...

Comment: I agree. I would just do this during working hours.

Comment: I can't see any context you can possibly give that would make this anything other than a monstrous way to treat your employees.

Comment: Not enough info provided. No background. The answers you get are just speculation on the unsaid details.

Comment: @WesleyLong, not such an obscure reference.One of my favorite Vir quotes.

Comment: @SBoss I think you meant lose-lose situation. I don't see any "win" here. Asking people to put in additonal hours for free is bad enough, telling them to pay for it is an unbelievably stupid idea. Just a couple of ingredients to make this an absolute disaster would be making it mandatory and expensive.

Comment: Just in comparison, I just got an [**invitation**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F1reT.jpg) for a Friday Movie event. A) Is optional B) Is free C) Probably also include Free Snacks. D) Is during office hours. And even with all that positive benefits I still won't go. Imagine if you make mandatory and I have to pay for it.

Comment: @MaskedMan Management is trying to win without losing anything, but it's true that it is a lose-lose situation as management will not experience the desired effects.

Comment: @SBoss I see, I get now what you meant.

Answer (score 24):

If you are proposing to

1. Hold a team-building activity,
2. Make it mandatory, and
3. Make employees pay for it,

Then I'd say this was a crappy, and possibly illegal, thing to do. If it's entirely voluntary, or if it's mandatory but company-paid, there are no problems, of course. But requiring employees to spend their own money is always shaky ground.

Comment: Even if it's not illegal, your employees will resent being forced to pay for the team building activity. It will certainly help them bond over their resentment of you, but that's probably not the outcome you want.

Comment: If you're making it mantadory and after hours, it's probably also illegal in many places.

Comment: And by the way, "strongly suggested", or any difference in the way OP will treat team members who didn't go, equals mandatory for most intents and purposes.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere sounds like coercion/extortion to me. "Buy this service you don't want or else".

Comment: @JoeStrazzere if you took it to court, this is probably what it would end up as. I can't imagine any company trying to ACTUALLY force people to show up and then pay for it themselves, though.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Maybe the `"ask"` part isn't Illegal. But if they retaliate because your didn't pay that is a different story. Now if my boss told me I have to pay for the bonding or for the printer toner I start looking for a new job.

Answer (score 9):

This sounds like a fantastic idea for team bonding ... except that it will work differently from what you expect. To make it more effective, choose an activity that costs an exorbitant amount but nobody likes, make it mandatory and do it after work hours.

This would ensure that the team members are either so annoyed that they leave on their own, or so demotivated that their work suffers and they would be fired. Then you can hire a brand new team which you can build from scratch.

In addition, depending on what the team thinks of the boss *now*, the team bonding event can produce great results in a different way. If the team members already hate the boss individually in secret, the team bonding event may cause the hate to spill over and encourage team members to <s>bitch about</s> praise the boss publicly. Nothing unites a team better than praising the boss.

Comment: Gee, I didn't know you felt like you had to lose some rep for some reason?

Comment: +1 for making me laugh and hopefully getting the correct point across.

Comment: Why so negative? There might also be a far different effect: It might unite the team in their hatred for fdskjhgfkj8o7. A common enemy is a great way to bind a group of people together. After such an experience they might show extraordinary teamwork and camaraderie when it comes to sabotaging fdskjhgfkj8o7's leadership.

Comment: @Weckar The answer is deliberately sarcastic to rub in the point strongly. In some cases like this, that is a lot more effective than writing a thesis.

Comment: @WeckarE. Lose rep? That's +66 right there.

Comment: Although that +66 is due to the +15240 that preceded it. :)

Answer (score 6):

You want the team to bond. You're doing this to benefit the company. Therefore, it should be considered part of "work" - i.e. the company pays for it, and it's done - if possible - during working hours.

What you're proposing is like asking them to work overtime, and to pay for the heating and electricity they use during the overtime! OK the team-bonding activity might be a bit more pleasant than the usual work they do, but it's still part of work.

Having said that you don't give us enough detail. If your "team-bonding activity" is simply you inviting them (i.e. optional) for a night out in the pub or something, then it might be reasonable to expect them to buy their own drink. (Though many companies might pick up the tab or at least some of it even in this case! Depending on culture of course)